# Issue updating UIPickerView in Swift with user inputted data into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I'm writing a simple fitness app that allows the user to add user profiles which are displayed in a `UIPickerView`, and when selected, is entered into the `profileField` label on the main `ViewController`. The `pickerView` uses an array of `Profile` objects as its data source and displays the name of the profile in the picker. I have it set up to where the user clicks a button on the main `ViewController` and is segued to the `AddProfileViewController` where they input the necessary requirements to create a profile. When they hit submit the information successfully gets appended to the `profileNames` array but the `pickerView` does not show any changes when the user clicks back on it. I have tried using `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` and `pickerView.reloadComponent(1)` to no success.

I am on Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    

    @IBOutlet weak var profileField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func didTapEnter(_ sender: Any)
    {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapNewProfile(_ sender: Any)
    {

    }
    
//these are pre-populated values in this array 
    var profileNames: [Profile] =
    [
        Profile("Brandon", 2, 120, 20, "Male"), 
        Profile("G", 2, 100, 20, "Male"),
        Profile("K", 1.6, 111, 19, "Male"),
        Profile("F", 2.1, 95, 20, "Male"),
        Profile("J", 1.89, 97.5, 21, "Male")
    ]
    
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        
        profileField.inputView = pickerView
        profileField.textAlignment = .center
        profileField.placeholder = "Enter Profile"
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return profileNames.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return profileNames[row].name
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        profileField.text = profileNames[row].name
        profileField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func profileSubmit(_ data: Profile)
    {
        profileNames.append(data)
        pickerView.reloadComponent(1) //This does not seem to do anything for me
    }
}
```

```
class AddProfileViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sexTextField: UITextField!
    
    let main: ViewController? = nil
    
    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let name = String(nameTextField.text!)
        let height = Double(heightTextField.text!)!
        let weight = Double(weightTextField.text!)!
        let age = Double(ageTextField.text!)!
        let sex = String(sexTextField.text!)
        let new = Profile.init(name, height, weight, age, sex)
        
        
        main?.profileSubmit(new)
        new.display()
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that on coming back from newProfile viewDidLoad is called -> you reset the picker in viewDidLoad by setting it to a new instance. Try to remove the new initialization in viewDidLoad :

```
super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView = UIPickerView()
```

The picker is already initialized here:

```
 var pickerView = UIPickerView()
```

Also, I think the picker components start with 0 - so if there is only 1 component it should be:

```
pickerView.reloadComponent(0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix this. I actually added this beforehand randomly to see if it would fix the issue in the first place (which of course it didn't).